# Baking bread during the day

Tags: baking, bread

Why is it that bread made during the day is lighter than bread made in the early morning

Comment: Most likely thing is that your room is warmer.

Comment: @derobert That should be an answer. It makes sense.

Comment: @Jolenealaska Yeah, I probably should have posted it as an answer, but now rfusca has beaten me too it.

Answer (score 8):

*All* other factors - ambient temperature, humidity, oven temp, etc - accounted for, the specific time of the day doesn't make any difference, whatsoever.

But alas, this is the real world, we don't hold other factors constant.  Most likely your room is slightly warmer and potentially your room could be a bit more humid in the afternoon.  These *could* lead to a more risen product if unaccounted for.  But overall, its not the *time* of the day.

---

One caveat- There does appear to be some (and by some, I mean a [single published paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20133849) that I can locate) evidence to suppose circadian cycles in yeast.  This would indicate a faster growth rate in the day.  But the evidence is underwhelming currently and is almost certainly overpowered by other environmental conditions if present at all.